# Inconsistent behaviour with ui:inputRadio when state changed externally

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

**Background**

I have some images `img` and radio options `ui:inputRadio`

```
<img alt="visa" onclick="{!c.handleCreditCardLogoClick }" src="{!$Resource.cclogos + '/logo-download-centre_visa.png'}" />
<img alt="mastercard" onclick="{!c.handleCreditCardLogoClick }" src="{!$Resource.cclogos + '/logo-download-centre_mastercard.png'}" />

<ui:inputRadio aura:id="visa" name="type" text="visa" change="{!c.handleCreditCardChange}" />
<ui:inputRadio aura:id="mastercard" name="type" text="mastercard" change="{!c.handleCreditCardChange}" />
```

When the logo is clicked, I want to update the correct radio button.

My code works if you only click the logos or only click on the radio options.

**JavaScript Controller:**

```
handleCreditCardChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let creditcard = event.getSource().get("v.text");
    // do stuff
},
handleCreditCardLogoClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let creditcard = event.target.alt;
    let option = cmp.find(creditcard);
    option.set("v.value", true);
}
```

If you click on a radio option, then click on a logo, the logo click does not change the state of the related radio option.

**Question**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I get a consistent behaviour when clicking on either the logo or radio option?